# Formatting table using booktabs

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am having a bit of a trouble with a table. The code for the table looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*\rotbf[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbr]
\centering
\label{tbl:heatwheel_res}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameter} & \specialcell{Exhaust\\air} & \specialcell{Exhaust and \\ outdoor air} & \specialcell{Heat wheel\\(80~\%)} \\
\midrule
Heat recovery [\%] & 89,6 \% & 89,6 \% & 77,4 \% \\
Real heat recovery [\%] & 50,5 \% & 52,1 \% & - \\
Net energy need for VH and SH & 27,7 & 27,0 & 15,8 \\
\specialcell{Delivered energy for\\DHW, VH and SH} & 31,1 & 27,6 & 45,6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I'm using `\specialcell` in order to break the line of elements that are too long. However, I want the text in the first row to be bold. When I add `\textbf{}` inside `\specialcell`, the document will not compile. Error message is: "`Missing } inserted`".

Do you have any suggestions? Can I make a new specialcell (`\specialcell2`) that is automatically bold?

Another question: How can I force the table to be a bit wider, in order to increase the space between the first column and the second column? I think column 1 and 2 are a bit too close at row 4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the whole outer cell, which contains `\specialcell` should be bold, `\bfseries` can be specified in the outer cell, right before `\specialcell`:

```
... & \bfseries\specialcell{...} & ...
```

This can also be put into a macro `\specialcellbold`, see the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand*\rotbf[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\specialcellbold}[2][c]{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbr]
\centering
\label{tbl:heatwheel_res}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameter} &
\specialcellbold{Exhaust\\air} &
\specialcellbold{Exhaust and\\ outdoor air} &
\specialcellbold{Heat wheel\\(80~\%)} \\
\midrule
Heat recovery [\%] & 89,6 \% & 89,6 \% & 77,4 \% \\
Real heat recovery [\%] & 50,5 \% & 52,1 \% & - \\
Net energy need for VH and SH & 27,7 & 27,0 & 15,8 \\
\specialcell{Delivered energy for\\DHW, VH and SH} & 31,1 & 27,6 & 45,6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The table formatted a little different:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}% It can also be loaded explicitly, implicitly it is
%                     loaded by siunitx
\usepackage{siunitx}
% \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}% OP now wants to have the default dot
\sisetup{detect-weight, mode=text}
\newcommand*\rotbf[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][b]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\specialcellbold}[2][b]{%
  \bfseries
  \sisetup{text-rm=\bfseries}%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\leftspecialcell}[2][b]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbr]
\centering
\label{tbl:heatwheel_res}
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{S[table-format=2.1]}}
\toprule
\textbf{Parameter} &
{\specialcellbold{Exhaust\\air}} &
{\specialcellbold{Exhaust and\\ outdoor air}} &
{\specialcellbold{Heat wheel\\(\SI{80}{\percent})}} \\
\midrule
Heat recovery [\si{\percent}] & 89,6 & 89,6 & 77,4 \\
Real heat recovery [\si{\percent}] & 50,5 & 52,1 & {---} \\
Net energy need for VH and SH & 27,7 & 27,0 & 15,8 \\
\leftspecialcell{Delivered energy for\\
  \quad DHW, VH and SH} & 31,1 & 27,6 & 45,6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Alternative result]

**Remarks:**

- Bottom aligned header row.
- Columns 2 to 4 are centered.
- Use of package [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) for aligning at the decimal marker and for setting the percent signs.
- The lines after the first line in a left cell is indented.
  and the alignment follows the bottom line instead of vertical
  centering.
- Use of em dash instead of the hyphen for the missing entry.
- Redundant percent signs removed.
- Changed the output decimal marker to the default dot (see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217857/formatting-table-using-booktabs/217858?noredirect=1#comment510779_217858) of ROLF).
- A little crude is `\siunit{text-rm=\bfseries}`. Option `detect-weight` did not work inside an `S`-column.

**Update**

I, Svend Tveskæg, found the code not very easy to read to I cleaned it up a bit (I hope it's okay):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
%  output-decimal-marker = {,},
  detect-weight,
  mode = text
}
\newcommand*{\specialcell}[2][b]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\specialcellbold}[2][b]{%
  \bfseries
  \sisetup{text-rm = \bfseries}%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\leftspecialcell}[2][b]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
 \label{tbl:heatwheel-res}
  \begin{tabular}{l *{3}{S[table-format = 2.1]}}
   \toprule
    \textbf{Parameter}                                    &
    {\specialcellbold{Exhaust    \\ air}}                 &
    {\specialcellbold{Exhaust and\\ outdoor air}}         &
    {\specialcellbold{Heat wheel \\ (\SI{80}{\percent})}}       \\
   \midrule
    Heat recovery [\si{\percent}]         & 89,6 & 89,6 & 77,4  \\
    Real heat recovery [\si{\percent}]    & 50,5 & 52,1 & {---} \\
    Net energy need for VH and SH         & 27,7 & 27,0 & 15,8  \\
    \leftspecialcell{Delivered energy for                       \\
    \quad DHW, VH and SH}                 & 31,1 & 27,6 & 45,6  \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton The example has three lines, which start with `\bfseries\specialcell`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `\specialcell` in the last row should not be bold, but use the same font as the other entries in the first column below the header row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That it exactly how I want it! However, there are some errors in your code (the last one). Could you please update the code? :) For example, you defined specialcell two times (and did not define specialcellbold). I get some other errors as well when trying to compile.

Comment: EDIT: I've decided to change to using "." instead of "," for decimals. Do I still need "\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}"?

Comment: @ROLF You can use the default of `siunitx` (a dot) or the explicit `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={.}`.

Comment: I get an error in line 10 and 23 when compiling in Sharelatex. I usually use Texmaker, but it shouldn't be dependent on the editor I'm using?

Comment: @ROLF Fixed now.

Comment: Now that you have loaded the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, you should use `\si{\percent}` instead of `\%` (in three places). Also, maybe use an em dash instead of an en dash for the empty entry.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Instead of `\mbox{--}` you can just use `{--}`, because `siunitx` will understand from the brace that a non numeric entry has been given and will center the item. Similarly for `\mbox{\specialcell{...}` that can just be `{\specialcell{...}}`. It's faster, because no expansion to find an unexpandable token is required.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Furthermore, replace `S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=2.1]` by `*{3}{S[table-format=2.1]}` and there's no point in `\usepackage{array}`.

Comment: Thank you so much for all replies, especially HeikoOberdiek. \usepackage{array} was may bad. I didn't know if it was used in the table or not.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, `\mbox{...}` removed in favor of `{...}`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Using `\SI{80}{\percent}` was tricky, because option `detect-weight` did not work inside an `S`-column. Also en dash fixed to em dash. `*{<n>}{...}` is practical here, but it has the disadvantage, that the format of a single column cannot be easily changed. Package `array` is loaded by `siunitx`, thus it does not matter much, if is is loaded explicitly.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've formatted the code a bit to make it more readable; I hope it's okay.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `[b]` and the `[c]` in `\newcommand*{\specialcell}[2][b]{...` and `\newcommand{\specialcellbold}[2][c]{...`

Comment: @thymaro `[b]` and `[c]` are the default values for the first parameter of `\specialcell` that is then passed as first optional argument for `\begin{tabular}` with meaning vertical alignment (`b` = bottom, `c` = centered).

Answer (score 6):

Just for comparison. How to do this table in plain TeX. But it works in LaTeX (without any loaded package) too.

```
\def\toprule{\noalign{\medskip\hrule height .8pt\medskip}}
\def\midrule{\noalign{\medskip\hrule\medskip}}
\let\bottomrule=\toprule
\def\specialcell#1{$\vcenter{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\strut\cr#1\cr}}$}
\def\x{\phantom{\%}}\def\h{\hfill\null}

\halign{&\ \hfil#\unskip\ \hfil\cr
\toprule
\bf Parameter\h & \bf\specialcell{Exhaust\cr air} &
                  \bf\specialcell{Exhaust and\cr outdoor air} &
                  \bf\specialcell{Heat wheel\cr(80~\%)} \cr
\midrule
Heat recovery [\%]\h &89,6 \% & 89,6 \% & 77,4 \% \cr
Real heat recovery [\%]\h & 50,5 \% & 52,1 \% & --- \cr
Net energy need for VH and SH & 27,7 \x & 27,0 \x & 15,8 \x \cr
\specialcell{Delivered energy for\cr DHW, VH and SH\hfill}\h& 31,1 \x & 27,6 \x & 45,6 \x\cr
\bottomrule
}

\bye
```

[image: tabule]

Comment: Amazing how compact the code is. I would suggest to left-align header of the first column, though.

Comment: I used this code to test if can be typeseted a table that runs across columns and pages in a memoir's two column document and found that works. Naturally, does not have continuation headers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel: the `makecell` package: its `\thead` and `\makecell` commands  allows for linebreaks in cells and a common formatting. It also  defines  `\rothead` and `\rotcell` commands if you load the `rotating` package. Demo:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbr]
\centering
\label{tbl:heatwheel_res}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\makecell{\bfseries Parameter} & \thead{Exhaust\\air} & \thead{Exhaust and \\ outdoor air} & \thead{Heat wheel\\(80~\%)} \\
\midrule
\makecell{Heat recovery\\{}[\%]} & 89,6 & 89,6 & 77,4 \\
\makecell{Real heat recovery\\{}[\%]} & 50,5 & 52,1 & -- \\
\makecell{Net energy need for\\VH and SH} & 27,7 & 27,0 & 15,8 \\
\makecell{Delivered energy for\\DHW, VH and SH} & \rotcell{31,1 }& 27,6 & 45,6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is `\thead` defined? I solves a problem that I commonly have with table headers. BTW: code and image don't seem to fit together for the last column.

Comment: @Christian Lindig: there was a typo in my answer: I wrote `\head` instead of `\thead`. It's defined in the `makedell` package. But I don't see what doesn't correspond to my code in the image?

Comment: Sorry, Safari hadn't shown me the horizontal scroll bar and I had missed the header for the last column in the code.