# Automatic resize table

Tags: tables, resize

I have this output:

[image]

**Problem**

Instead of hardcoding the resize parameter '0.8' in `\resizebox{0.8\columnwidth}{!}{[...]}` - I would like to make some sort of automatic resize function.

I have these two requirements:

- I want the table to fill as much as possible/the rest of the page (in height/length of the paper)
- But only to the extend, that the columnwidt of the table does not exceed the textwidth

Any idea of how to write this function in Latex?
Or links to sources which may help me further with this task.

**Tex Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\section{Text}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 


\section{Table}
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{0.8\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{5}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                         &                                &                                &                                &                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{7}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{8}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{9}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at `tabularx`.

Comment: Why do you use all these `\multicolumn`: only for the rules?

Comment: applying resizebox to tables should be avoided in almost all cases it is only ever a last resort and even then avoid it, certainly never want to apply it automatically.  It produces inconsistent font sizes and rule widths.

Comment: To NBur, I just generated the table in https://www.tablesgenerator.com/, it was faster than writing it myself. I gueess it's an leftover from last time I used tablegenerator

Comment: To David Charlisle, thanks for the warning. I didn't came across this problem yet and have tried with different parameters. Do you have any other solution to resize the table?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your table to fit a given width, `tabularx` (thanks @David Carlisle!) is the way to go.

To simplify, I set up a new column type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % from array package

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Text}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \section{Table}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \resizebox{0.8\columnwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tabular}{lllll}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{5}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                                         &                                &                                &                                &                                \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{7}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{8}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{9}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{12} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[H]
            \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|l*{4}{|C}|}
                \hline
                1  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                2  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                3  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                4  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                5  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                6  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                   &           &           &           &           \\ \hline
                7  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                8  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                9  & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                10 & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                11 & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                12 & Something & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
            \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I was searching. I would like to adjust it in the height aswell

Comment: Could you elaborate the ```{|l*{4}{|C}|}``` part

Comment: What about @David's warning? If you need there is the `ltablex` package, merging the `longtable` and `tabularx` to deal with tabular on multi pages and with the X column type.

Comment: The `|` are for vertical rules, `*{num}{columntype}` says I want `num` columns with the same `columntype`

Comment: Thans for the clarification. I'm trying to work around the warning so instead of resizing, then using tabularx as you proposed, but adjusting in the height also by inserting air in the height. (Sorry for the bad explanation, but that is what I'm trying to accompilish, if I succeeds it will sure be more beautifull than my attempt with resize)

Comment: Thanks @campa: I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As supplement to @Nbur answer ...

- as already mentioned, use of use of the `\resizebox` lead to inconsistency  between fonts size in table an in other text.
- use of `multicolumn{1}{...}{...}` are just clutter in code
- use of `[H]` as placement specification is dangerous. It can result in unexpected result as undesired empty spaces.
- it is not clear, what you imagine with *vertical stretching of table* ... it also lead to change font size
- do you really want to have an very ugly designed table?

Answer of @Nbur shows the way, how you can write a table. Here is just a cleanup of used code and some improvements in height of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\section{Text}
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\section{Table}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} % <---
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|C|C|X|X|}
    \hline
1   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
2   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
3   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
4   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
5   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
6   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
    &            &            &            &            \\ \hline
7   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
8   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
9   & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
10  & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
11  & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
12  & Something  & Something  & Something  & Something  \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And to correct a bit more the “ugly design”, you can use the booktab package ([for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217857/formatting-table-using-booktabs)).

Comment: Of course I don't want an ugly ass table xD The table was just generated in a website, only for this question. Well my problem is a have a lot of pages each concerning different topics and in the end of each of these pages there is an table. Some of the tables are inches too large to go on the same page as the text and other tables are very small so the page looks empty. So I thought I could automatic resize them, such that the filled as much as possible and the big ones get a little smaller to be contained at the page. I didn't thought so much of the impact of the fonts.

Comment: But I'm aware now, so thank you all for that. And especially thank you for the code to extend in width and height without changing the font.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a resize of the whole table, but with some automation, have a look at the `fitbox` package: you can specify min and max lengths to adjust the content.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fitbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Text}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \section{Table}
    \begin{table}[H]
%       \resizebox{0.8\columnwidth}{!}{
        \fitbox[maxwidth=\columnwidth]{
            \begin{tabular}{lllll}
                \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{2}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{4}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{5}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
                \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Something} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \fitbox[maxwidth=\textwidth]{
            \begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
                \hline
                1  & Something\\% & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                2  & Something\\% & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                3  & Something\\% & Something & Something & Something \\ \hline
                4  & Something\\ \hline
            \end{tabular}}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]